# How to capture only last match in Regex

Tags: regex

I have the string below (including line breaks) that is returned from a TFS 'Labels' command. I need to match against only the last build number (build.2).

How do I build a regex expression to do this?

```
Label                                                  Owner          Date      
---------------------------------------------------- -------------- ---------- 
ICSExternalGateway-04_MJR-ICSExternalGateway-build.0 Marchen, Keith 2/25/2015 
ICSExternalGateway-04_MJR-ICSExternalGateway-build.1 Marchen, Keith 2/25/2015
ICSExternalGateway-04_MJR-ICSExternalGateway-build.2 Marchen, Keith 2/25/2015
```

Comment: What **language** are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
build\.\d+(?![\s\S]*\bbuild\.\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.The lookahead will make sure there is no `build` ahead.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/14

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this. It works because ordinarily the wildcard character `.` does not match a newline:

```
(build.\d).*$
```

[See Regex 101 Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/yD8qX9/1) for example and full explanation.