# Regex, take last match before suffix

Tags: regex

I know this is going to sound like the kind of question that's been asked hundreds of times. But I've been searching for over an hour and none of the solution I found worked in my case.

I have many different numbers of the form

`\d*'?\d+\.\d\d`

An example of string I work with would be

> The base item costs 1'245.48, the tax is of 18.45 and the bonus of 250.00, the total price is of 1'013.93. In case of trouble, contact our e-mail. Bank account 784.45

I want to get ONLY the last match corresponding to my regex before `e-mail`, i.e `1'013.93`. I would like to use only regex, no extra python, javascript or anything

I have tried code inspired by this [Regex Last occurrence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374742/regex-last-occurrence), this [How to capture only last match in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734395/how-to-capture-only-last-match-in-regex), this [Find Last Occurrence of Regex Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490160/find-last-occurrence-of-regex-word), and many other expressions of my own, but so far there always seems to be one piece missing

For example, after successfully selecting the very last number with `(\d*'?\d+\.\d\d)(?!.*\d*'?\d+\.\d\d)`,  I tried `(\d*'?\d+\.\d\d)(?!.*\d*'?\d+\.\d\d)(?=e-mail)`, which does not match anything.

Any insights?

Comment: In your case that would be `(\d*'?\d+\.\d\d)(?:(?!\d+\.\d\d).)*e-mail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
((\d+')?\d+(\.\d+)?)(?=[^\d]+e-mail)
```

The first group matches the number you want. From regex101.com:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with an extra number format check:

```
((\d{1,3}')*(\d{1,3})\.\d{2})(?=\D+e-mail)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xYnYzL/1)